# XmlPullParser exception org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}content (position:START_TAG

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to parse a `XML` which is a thirdparty response when I call certain API. Here is the response of the `XML`:

```
<mojiva>
<ad type="thirdparty" feed="xyz">
<url>
  <![CDATA[ ]]>
</url>
<text>
  <![CDATA[ ]]>
</text>
<track>
  <![CDATA[ ]]>
</track>
<content>
  <script> // Original sdk: "http://lp.mydas.mobi/custom/rich/common/js/mmisdk/mmsdk.min.js" </script>
</content>
</ad>
</mojiva>
```

I'm trying to parse `<content>` tag, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
12-16 06:40:55.148: W/System.err(4089): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}content (position:START_TAG <text>@1:116 in     java.io.InputStreamReader@a6a613e0) 
12-16 06:40:55.148: W/System.err(4089):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2046)
```

**Updated Code:**
I'm parsing the `XML` using `XmlPullParser`. Here is what my code looks like:

```
public class AdPull {

private static final String ns = null;
List<Entry> all;
InputStream is;

public AdPull(InputStream open) {
    is = open;
}

public List<Entry> getData() {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(is, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        all = (ArrayList<Entry>) readFeed(parser);
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {

            Log.i("........", "" + all.get(i).url);
            Log.i("........", "" + all.get(i).text);
            Log.i("........", "" + all.get(i).track);
            Log.i("........", "" + all.get(i).thirdPartyContent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return all;
}

private List<Entry> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "mojiva");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("ad")) {
            entries.add(readAd(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}

private Entry readAd(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "ad");

    String url = null;
    String text = null;
    String track = null;
    String content = null;
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        Log.i("...............", name);
        if (name.equals("url")) {
            url = readUrl(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("text")) {
            text = readTexta(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("track")) {
            track = readTrack(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("content")) {
            content = readContent(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return new Entry(url, text, track, content);
}

private String readContent(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "content");
    String content = null;
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("script")) {
            content = readScript(parser);
            Log.i(".......", content);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }

    return content;
}

private String readScript(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "script");
    String script = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "script");
    return script;
}

private String readUrl(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "url");
    String url = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "url");
    return url;
}

private String readTexta(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "text");
    String text = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "text");
    return text;
}

private String readTrack(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "track");
    String track = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "track");
    return track;
}

private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}

private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            depth--;
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            depth++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm calling getData() from my MainActivity in async task:

```
class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, List<Entry>, List<Entry>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Entry> doInBackground(Void... sUrl) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(completeURL);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
            String _respons = EntityUtils.toString(ht);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(_respons.getBytes());
            AdPull ad = new AdPull(is); // expects a input stream
            List<Entry> list = ad.getData();

            return list;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can some comment, why downvote? Before giving anyone downvote, explain the reason why?

Comment: `else if (type.equals("thirdparty"))` there is no tag by the name thirdparty

Comment: @Raghunandan `type = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "type");`. I'm getting type of the response from it and doing stuff accordingly. That is working fine I checked it. If `type` is `thirdparty` it is going inside, otherwise it is not. So, I think that can't be the issue here.

Comment: you need to parse script inside content

Comment: @Raghunandan I just want to print all the values inside `<content>`, for now I want to ignore `<script>` tag. Any comments from your side?

Comment: there is not value inside content tag there is another tag called script

Comment: @Raghunandan For `<script>` tag then, will I have to make separate method? Inside `<content>` tag read method? Or it can be done by any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I can't read <content> tag from the response
```

Under tag content you have tag script. So you need to parse script tag also

```
<content>
  <script> // Original sdk: "http://lp.mydas.mobi/custom/rich/common/js/mmisdk/mmsdk.min.js" </script>
</content>
```

Example :

I added dummy values for testing. I put the xml in assests folder and i parsed the xml as below

```
<mojiva>

    <ad
        feed="xyz"
        type="thirdparty" >

        <url>
                <![CDATA[http://google.com]]>
        </url>

        <text>
                <![CDATA[my text]]>
        </text>

        <track>
                 <![CDATA[my track]]>
        </track>

        <content>

            <script>
   "http://lp.mydas.mobi/custom/rich/common/js/mmisdk/mmsdk.min.js" 
            </script>
        </content>
    </ad>

</mojiva>
```

And  parsing

```
InputStream is = MainActivity.this.getResources().getAssets().open("xmlparser.xml");
new Testing(is);
```

Then

```
    public class Testing {

    InputStream is;
    ArrayList<AllEntry> all;
    private static final String ns = null;
    public Testing(InputStream is) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.is = is;
        getData(); 
    }
    public List<AllEntry> getData() {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(is, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            all = (ArrayList<AllEntry>) readFeed(parser);
            for(int i=0;i<all.size();i++)
            {

                Log.i("........",""+all.get(i).url);
                Log.i("........",""+all.get(i).text);
                Log.i("........",""+all.get(i).track);
                Log.i("........",""+all.get(i).content);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return all;
    }

    private List<AllEntry> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        List<AllEntry> entries = new ArrayList<AllEntry>();
       String value=null;
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "mojiva");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("ad")) {
                String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "feed");  
                  if (relType.equals("xyz")){
                      value = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "type");
                   if(value.equals("thirdparty"))   
                    entries.add(readAd(parser));

              }

            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return entries;
    }

    private AllEntry readAd(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "ad");

        String url = null;
        String text = null;
        String track = null;
        String content = null;
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            Log.i("...............",name);
            if (name.equals("url")) {
                url = readUrl(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("text")) {
                text= readTexta(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("track")) {
               track = readTrack(parser);
            } 
            else if (name.equals("content")) {
                   content = readContent(parser);
                }else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return new AllEntry(url, text, track,content);
    }


    private String readContent(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "content");
         String content = null;
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("script")) {
             content=   readScript(parser);
             Log.i(".......",content);
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }  

        return content;
    }
    private String readScript(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "script");
        String url = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "script");
        return url;
    }
    private String readUrl(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "url");
        String url = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "url");
        return url;
    }

    private String readTexta(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "text");
        String text = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "text");
        return text;
    }
    private String readTrack(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "track");
        String track = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "track");
        return track;
    }
     private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
            String result = "";
            if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                result = parser.getText();
                parser.nextTag();
            }
            return result;
        }

    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static class AllEntry{
        //public final String ad;
        public final String url;
        public final String text;
        public final String track;
        public final String content;

        private AllEntry(String url, String text,String track,String content) {
            this.url = url;
            this.text = text;
            this.track = track;
            this.content= content;

        }
    }
}
```

Log

```
12-16 03:04:02.956: I/........(1932):                 http://google.com
12-16 03:04:02.956: I/........(1932):         
12-16 03:04:02.956: I/........(1932):                 my text
12-16 03:04:02.956: I/........(1932):         
12-16 03:04:02.956: I/........(1932):                  my track
12-16 03:04:02.956: I/........(1932):         
12-16 03:04:02.966: I/........(1932):    "http://lp.mydas.mobi/custom/rich/common/js/mmisdk/mmsdk.min.js"
```

Comment: I have updated the code in my question. I have tried your solution but the thing is that it is not going inside the `readContent()` method, can you please see the updated code, and tell what am I missing?

Comment: @Anupam try the edited code now. it will work. See the log also.

Comment: @Anupam copy paste my code and try. meanwhile i will check what's wrong with your updated code.

Comment: @Anupam i tried your code also works. where do you call `getData` and use `Log` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: @Anupam also there is not img tag in your xml So this is useless  `else if (name.equals("img"))`. Please copy paste my code and use the same xml you posted. If you are tags are different the posted code won't work. So if tags changes you need to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the code and now you can see from where I'm calling `getData()`. Still I can't read the data inside `readContent()`, this method is being called but `if (name.equals("script")) {` is never being called?

Comment: @Anupam pls use the code in my post. Absolutely works.I tried before posting and can you see the log. What more can i do. Posted every thing. pls make the modifications

Comment: @Anupam can't read means what you see in the log post the log also

Comment: Getting null there in content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43272/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-anupam)

Comment: @Anupam join chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43272/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-anupam

Comment: I have to only parse <content> tag not the <script> tag.  Now it is working and solves my purpose. Marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<String> tags = new LinkedList<String>();
tags.add("url");
tags.add("text");
tags.add("track");
XmlResourceParser xml = getResources().getXml(R.xml.m);
try {
    for (int type = xml.next(); type != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT; type = xml.next()) {
        if (type == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
            String name = xml.getName();
            if (tags.contains(name)) {
                type = xml.next();
                Log.d(TAG, "tag: " + name + ", value: " + xml.getText());
            }
        }
    }
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and this is res/xml/m.xml:

```
<mojiva>
<ad type="thirdparty" feed="xyz">
<url>
<![CDATA[some url]]>
</url>
<text>
<![CDATA[sample text]]>
</text>
<track>
<![CDATA[unknown track]]>
</track>
<content>
<script> // Original ble ble ble </script>
</content>
</ad>
</mojiva>
```